# avoid fixed size values in grid/stackpanel in xaml in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am attaching a image[image]

I wanna create gap between MyTask(text) and setting image icon. I can achieve it using margin property. but when my windows phone orientation changes it looks bad. Is there a way that my setting image will always stick to right side and text on left side. how can i create gap between text and image, by avoiding fixed values.
this is my code.

```
 <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="35" Source="/Assets/Icons/MyTasks.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="MY TASKS"></TextBlock>                    
                <Image Margin="200,0,0,0" Grid.Column="3" Height="40" Source="/Assets/Icons/Settings.png"></Image>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: You could use a DockPanel

Comment: DockPanel Control is not available in Windows Phone 8 app.

Comment: Have you tried HorizontalContentAlignment left on the textblock and right on the Image? Sorry, I can't test right now.

Comment: HorizontalContentAligment property is not available in windows phone 8 app. i have tried horizontalalignment property, but it din work. i dont understand why Microsoft behave like this. i have a pivot control, i am doing this in the title of the pivot control, so the text will be on left side and image will be on right side. with fixed margin, it works fine in portrait mode but in landscape mode it fails,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [sample](http://sdrv.ms/1dkFtfC).

This is excerpt of the Pivot template. First and third column definition must be: `Width="Auto"`.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image
        Height="35"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="12,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Source="/Assets/Icons/MyTasks.png" />

    <ContentControl
        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="0,0,0,-7"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleStyle}"/>

    <Image
        Grid.Column="2"
        Height="35"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Source="/Assets/Icons/Settings.png" />

</Grid>
```